# preg replace in vbulletin 4 template

Tags: php, vbulletin

I want code to replace a word in a vbulletin template on a hook (global_start ....)

the code in vb3

```
$vbulletin->templatecache['SHOWTHREAD'] = preg_replace("#word#", "replace", $vbulletin->templatecache['SHOWTHREAD']);
```

but I want it for vbulletin 4

Answer (score 0):

You should use str_replace instead:

```
$vbulletin->templatecache['SHOWTHREAD'] = str_replace("word", "replace", $vbulletin->templatecache['SHOWTHREAD']);
```